# glossaries-extra \glsaddkey footnote is not working

Tags: footnotes, acronyms, german, glossaries-extra, grammar

I'm writing my master thesis in german language using glossaries-extra for handling all the acronyms and stuff. Due to the german grammar, I need for some acronyms additional entries for the first appearance (with full text). I handled this with \glsaddkey. Problem now is that the appearance is default, so the settings I set in the header (footnote in particular) aren't working.
I tried several different variants of rewriting commands and stuff, but nothing is really working.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[footnote, acronym, nomain]{glossaries-extra}

\parindent0pt

\makeglossaries

% Extension for displaying user1-value in appendix
\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{%
    \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
    { (\glscurrentfieldvalue)}%
    {}%
}

% Extension for the use of different grammatical variants (won't be displayed in appendix)
\glsaddkey*{adj}%
    {\glsentrytext{\glslabel}XXXGEN}%
    {\glsentryadj}%
    {\Glsentryadj}%
    {\glsadj}%
    {\Glsadj}%
    {\GLSadj}%

% Stil specification to look like \acronym
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\acronymtype] \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}
\newglossarystyle{owngloss}{%
    \setglossarystyle{treegroup}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glsentryitem{##1}\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
        \\ \glossentrydesc{##1} \\ \par
    }%
}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}

\newacronym[user1 = periods per revolution]{ppr}{PPR}{Perioden pro Umdrehung}
\newacronym[adj = {magnetoresistiven}]{mr}{MR}{magnetoresistiv}
\newacronym[adj = {Dual}]{dual}{Dual-Code}{Aus der Digitaltechnik bekanntes dyadisches Codesystem}
\newacronym{485}{RS-485}{ANSI/TIA/EIA-485-A-1998}

\begin{document}

\gls{ppr}
\\
\glsadj{mr}
\\
\glsadj{dual}
\\
\gls{485}

\printglossary[title = Begriffsverzeichnis, style = alttree]

\end{document}
```

I tried to edit the linkhook and stuff, but I can't get the footref working.

```
\newcommand{\ADJglspostlinkhook}{\footnote{\gls}}
\newcommand{\glsadjx}[1]{{\let\glspostlinkhook\ADJglspostlinkhook\glsadj{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround even without the additional definition of the \glsaddkey-methode:

```
\glsdesk{mr}{magnetoresistiven}\footnote{\glsdesc{mr}}
```

Comment: If it works, then you can accept your own answer is the best...